# How to static-import enums residing in separate files in Java?

Tags: java, import, enums

Basically, here's the gist of my code:

```
// File: ShapeColor.java
package mypackage;

public enum ShapeColor
{
    MAUVE,
    PURPLE,
    VIOLET;
}

// File: ShapeSize.java
package mypackage;

public enum ShapeSize
{
    TINY,
    SMALL,
    MEDIUM,
    LARGE,
    HUGE,
    COLOSSAL;
}

// File: Shape.java
import static mypackage.ShapeSize.*;
import static mypackage.ShapeColor.*;

public class Shape
{
    private ShapeSize size;
    private ShapeColor color;

    public Shape()
    {
        this(ShapeSize.MEDIUM, ShapeColor.PURPLE);
    }

    public Shape(ShapeSize ss, ShapeColor sc)
    {
        this.size = ss;
        this.color = sc;
    }
}
```

How can I `import static` my `enum` definitions so I can access the `enum` values without qualifying them? I have all my .java source files slapped in one directory and I'm compiling from the command line. I have no idea about packages and how to "organize" my source files in directories (or if I even should do so). I've tried reading about these concepts but all that did was get me more confused. I learn much better through examples and demo code than by reading documentation, unfortunately.

**EDIT:**

After adding `package mypackage;` to the `enum` files and `import static mypackage.*` to the `class` file. I get the following errors:

```java
.\ShapeSize.java:4: error: duplicate class: mypackage.ShapeSize
public enum ShapeSize
       ^
Shape.java:7: error: cannot access ShapeSize
    private ShapeSize size;
            ^
  bad source file: .\ShapeSize.java
    file does not contain class ShapeSize
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the sourcepath.
```

Comment: Your error means that you should also import `mypackage.ShapeSize` along with statically importing its values.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Indeed. I was too invested in my trials-and-errors that I didn't even see your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out!
Moved both `enum` source files to sub-folder called `mypackage` and also normal-`import`ed them in addition to `import static` their values. Shape class now starts like this:

```
import mypackage.ShapeSize;
import mypackage.ShapeColor;
import static mypackage.ShapeSize.*;
import static mypackage.ShapeColor.*;
```

**EDIT:**
Actually, no need to move the `enum` source files. Just had to standard-`import` them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
import static mypackage.ShapeColor.PURPLE;
import static mypackage.ShapeSize.MEDIUM;
```

Comment: That causes compiling errors. Check my edit to the main post.